# Display different content in a div

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, load

I want to change the contents of a div When a user clicks on a link. To do that, I tried using the following code :

```
function openModal() {
    el = document.getElementById("modal");
    el.style.visibility = "visible";
}    

function showContent(id) {
    openModal();
    $("#modal").load("modal/id.php");
    return false;
}
```

However, it doesn't change `"modal/id.php"` to `"modal/something.php"` and, in place of that, opens a file named `id.php` in the modal directory. How can I change that?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand what's your question. Perhaps this's the answer.

1. PHP

   ```
       echo "This other text is inside a PHP script";
   ```
2. HTML

[image]

Comment: That's not really what I want to do. In my website, I have multiple icons. When you click on one icon, a popup is displayed with some content in it. However, my code displays the same page for all the icons (a page called id.php). What I want to do is display a different page for each icon.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the rest of your code. It sounds like it may just be an ID oversight.

Comment: This would perhaps be better as a comment on the questions.

Comment: I tried that first. Got a message that I need 50 reputation points to post a comment on the question. Just trying to help...